# How to mock multiple fields of same type in GwtMockito

Tags: gwt, mocking

I understand that @GwtMock annotation creates a mock of a particular type when run with GwtMockitoTestRunner, but what if I had multiple items of a particular type in my widget? For example if I had many buttons, or many anchors in my widget, is there a way to create mocks for each one individually?

Right now I am thinking of bypassing this shortcoming in my test with something like

```
@GwtMock mockButtonn;
```

and then later on

```
when(mockButton.something()).thenReturn(value1,value2,value3,...)
```

so I can distinguish the buttons based on order of invocation. But this is definitely unmaintainable. Can someone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to use the mocks generated by GwtMockito, take a look at the documentation at http://google.github.io/gwtmockito/ if you haven't already. It depends on how you're creating your widgets:

1. If you're creating widgets via UiBinder (fields annotated with `@UiField`), you don't have to do anything special - they will automatically be filled with mocks when you call `createAndBindUi`. You can then reference them directly in your tests, e.g. `when(myClass.myLabel.getText()).thenReturn("some text")`. This works because fields have to be package-private for UiBinder, so you can see them from your tests.
2. If you're passing widgets into your class via its constructor or some other way ([dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)), then just declare fields in your test using the normal Mockito `@Mock` annotation. GwtMockito will invoke Mockito to fill these in automatically, but otherwise it's just the same as any other Mockito mock.
3. If you're creating widgets via `GWT.create`, this is where `@GwtMock` is valuable. The only difference between `@GwtMock` and `@Mock` is that `@GwtMock` also makes it so any calls to `GWT.create` will return the object annotated with `@GwtMock`. So it doesn't really make sense to annotate multiple fields of the same type with `@GwtMock`, since `GWT.create` can return only one of them.
4. If you're creating widgets directly via `new`, don't do that! It will be impossible to create fake version for testing, and you should use dependency injection instead.

1 and 2 are the most common cases by far - it's somewhat uncommon to actually have to use `@GwtMock`.

Comment: i see. what you have outlined in 1 was the case i was looking for at the time. i think i had misinterpreted the documentation and my understanding was that a single mock is created for the objects corresponding to a particular type, rather than a separate mock for each UiField.